# MySQL - When foreign key is changed, how to make a row of the old key delete at the same time?

Tags: mysql

I want my table1 have a "one-to-one" relationship with the other(table2).
And when the index of the table1 is changed, the index row of the table2 will be delete.
How can I do?

LIKE THE BELOW:

```
CREATE TABLE `database`.`table1`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `fileId` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL)
CREATE TABLE `database`.`table2`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `fileName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)
```

The fileId of the table1 is to one id of the table2.
And the fileId can be changed, when changed, the table2 will be delete, that means no file be used.
At last, we will create a new row to the table2.

Example:

table1 is for information of account, and every account can upload a file to the table2 or change the file. It's meaning that every row in table1 have a row in table2. And the index is the fileId of table1 that connects with the id of table2.

And I want the data in table2 can be deleted when the fileId in table1 is changed. Then every data in table2 must connect with one data in table1.

Comment: There aren't any indexes or foreign keys on the published tables? You could clarify this question by adding sample data and and expected result as text to the question.

Comment: I've adding the example in my question.

Comment: The table design is odd. If table2.id is supposed to relate to table1.fileid then it cannot be an auto_increment column but table2 should have a foreign key on id referencing table1.fileid.Also if there is a one to one relationship(;every account can upload A file')   between table1 and table2 then I don't  see the point of table2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger in `table1` on update. So your trigger will be as

```
CREATE TRIGGER `database`.`old_key_delete` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

delete from table2 where id=old.fileId;

END
```